# Ubuntu installation media

Tags: system-installation

I have a an HP laptop running Win 8.1 that now boots to a black screen, not responding to any keyboard or mouse events. No idea what the problem is and I haven't got a boot device that can help me.

How can I obtain an installation media with Ubuntu that I can use to scratch the laptop and convert it to an Ubuntu laptop?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the media for download from [this location.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

You will also find an install guide there.

If you use USB, you will need a tool to burn the iso image to USB. I have used the unetbootin a couple times with success

While [this guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html) is mainly for 12.04, I found it helpful the first time I installed.

Comment: Please don't just paste links in.